# Zend Framework, mapping the extension of a URL to the format parameter?

Tags: zend-framework, routes, format

It is possible to map the extension of a URL, to the format parameter in ZF?

I'd like the default routing to still work, including mapping parameters from the URI, so you'd be able to say:

> http://example.com/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2.json

Here: `$this->_getParam('format') => "json"`

And likewise:

> http://example.com/module/controller/action/param1/value1/param2/value2.xml

Here: `$this->_getParam('format') => "xml"`

I've fiddled with the default routes, but i cannot get it to work..

Answer (score 3):

You could create a regex route, ending with something like (\w+)(.(\w+))? and capture the part after the . as the .3 capture.  see [`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex)