# ZF routing - url with extension with Nth params

Tags: regex, zend-framework, zend-route

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202414/zend-framework-mapping-the-extension-of-a-url-to-the-format-parameter), I have accomplished passing the format with the url extension, but you have have to declare the parameters passed upfront. Example:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        '([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\.(\w+))?',
        array(
            'module'        => 'Default',
            'controller'    => 'index',
            'action'        => 'index',
        ),
        array(
            1    => 'module',
            2    => 'controller',
            3    => 'action',
            4    => 'extension',
            5    => 'format'
        )
);
```

But what if I want /:module/:controller/:action/*.:format???
So that no matter how many parameters I pass through the url, the '.whatever' will be the format parameter? Basically, I'm trying to take the default router and add extension as the 'format param'.

#### Edit:

The issue isn't grabbing the extension, the issue is adding other params. For example

```
/blogs/posts/view/post/500/foo/bar/format/html
```

will translate into:
    array('module'=>'blogs','controller'=>'posts', 'action' => 'view', 'post'=>500,  'format' => 'html', 'foo' => 'bar');

But I want to be able to represent the format the same route like so:

```
/blogs/post/view/post/500/foo/bar.html
```

No matter how many parameters are declared between the action and the format.

Comment: as far as i know there is no way to achieve this with standard routes

Comment: you can achieve this by extending route though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `whatever` you can specify with `.*` expression.

To match it - simply: `(.*)`

If you want not to grab for example extension, use `?`:

```
(.*?)(\.(\w+))
```

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear about what the issue is. See edit above